# How to configure browser to wait for a response before sending another request in MEAN application

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I have a MEAN application that runs test cases on a bunch of similarly coded application.
I send a request that triggers running the test cases on the application through Angular6 to ExpressJS.
Since there is a delay in receiving the response, the browser is re-sending the request, which re triggers the process.

I used `windows.location.reload()` and it did stop the browser from re-sending request. But the browser will not receive the response that the server sends once its done with the process.

Below is my Express code:

```
router.post("/trainee", (req, res, next) => {
    var empList = req.body.empList;
    var scriptCount = 0
    asyncLoop(empList, (empId, next) => {
        req.body.empId = empId;
        console.log("started Script", "empId : " + empId);
        return testunzip.decompress(req, res).then((msg) => {
            console.log("decompressed: ", msg);
            return testunzip.makeTempsolution(req, res).then((msg) => {
                console.log("temp soln : ", msg);
                return storage.testing(req, res).then((msg) => {
                    console.log("testing : ", msg);
                    return storage.fetchMarks(req, res).then((data) => {
                        data = jsonReport.parser(data, req, res)
                        scriptCount++
                        console.log("data in call: ", data)
                        next();
                    })
                })
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message)
            next();
        })
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
        }
        console.log('Evaluation completed for !' + scriptCount + ' scripts');
        res.send("Done!")
    })
})
```

This is my angular code:

```
evaluateScript(data) {
  this.traineesResult = null;
  this.errorMessage = null;
  data.empList = this.empList;
  data.folderName = this.folderName;
  this.service.evaluateScript(data).subscribe(
     (result) => { this.traineesResult = result },
     (err) => { this.errorMessage = err.error.message }
   )
   window.location.reload()
 }
```

How can I achieve my requirement? Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Please post your request code

Comment: the API is called [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: My code uses promise.
**asyncLoop** is an npm module `node-async-loop`